# Creating a helper function using the module pattern, want to make this a safe operation

Tags: javascript, jquery

My dom elements have this pattern for their id's:

```
id="some-blah-12342"
```

or

```
id="abc-1234"
```

So far I have:

```
SOME_THING.utils = (function() {


   return {
         getObjectId: function(d) {
              ?????????

     }

   };

})();
```

Then I will use it like this correct?

```
var linkId = SOME_THING.utils.getObjectId( $("#some-link").id );
```

**I want this to work if say the object passed to the function is undefined/nil or whatever.**

Comment: are you attempting to pass an id to a function that is supposed to get an id? which would be $("#some-link").attr('id')

Answer (score 0):

```
function getObjectId(obj){
    if(obj==undefined || obj==null){return null;}
    if(typeof obj == "string"){
        return $('#'+obj).attr('id');
    }else if(typeof obj == "object"){
        return $(obj).attr('id');
    }
    return null; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what your doing with the function but what i think you trying to do is extract the number

so if you had html that looked like this

```
<input type="text" id="some-blah-12342" class="test" />
```

you could use something like this to get the number

```
var id = $('.test:first').attr('id').match(/(\d+)/);
alert(id[0])
```